# Is it possible to graft miracle fruit to a rootstock that tolerates alkaline soil?

Tags: fruits, grafting, tropical, ph

I am interested in purchasing a miracle fruit (Synsepalum dulcificum) plant and would love to plant it in the ground.

However, one of the main issues is that miracle fruit likes extremely acidic soils and AZ has alkaline soil.

Does anyone know of a potential rootstock that would be compatible with miracle fruit and allow it to grow in alkaline soil?

I cannot find anything on Google about grafting miracle fruit and do not even know how to identify other plants in the same family to determine potential rootstock for miracle fruit. I don't even know if what I am trying to do is even possible so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Miracle fruit (Synsepalum dulcificum) belongs to the Sapotaceae family, and you'd need host roots from a plant within that family, though whether there are any suitable or compatible isn't something I know. But why not grow it in a pot - it's said to do well and fruit in containers, given the right conditions, even though it won't achieve its full, in the ground height of 10-15 feet. More info in the link below

https://toptropicals.com/html/toptropicals/plant_wk/synsepalum.htm